# Query for posts belonging to multiple categories

Tags: wp-query, categories, array, children

Within the default Post categories I have

1. A parent category Cities
   -- City A
   -- City B
   -- City C
2. A parent category Beauty
   -- Hairdressers
   -- Pedicure
3. A parent category Sightseeing
   -- Archeological
   -- Historical Building
   -- Castles
   -- Churches

I'm trying to build a query that is showing both the posts and the subcategory titles of the Beauty & Sightseeing category based on the City I'm publishing.

The current City is called by the `get_queried_object();`

The combination of posts in the child category Hairdressers for a specific City is called by

```
<!-- Query for kapper -->
<section>

    <div class="container">
        
        <?php 
        
        $Kapper = 6 ;
        $KapperName = "Kapper";
        
        $location_argument = array( 
        
        'category__and' => array( $location_id , $Kapper ) ,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        
        );
        
        $query = new WP_Query( $location_argument );
        
        ?>
                
        <div class="row">
        
        <?php 
        
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        
        ?>
        
        <h2><?php echo $KapperName; ?></h2>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col">
        
        <ul class="citydetails">
        
        <?php 
            
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            
            $query->the_post(); 
            
        ?>
        
        
        
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </a> - <?php the_field('afstand-van-anapurna') ?> km </li>
            
        
        
        
        <?php ;}} ?>
        
        
        </div>
        
        
        </ul>
        
        </div>
        
        <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
        ?>
        

    </div>

</section>
<!-- End of query for kapper -->
```

The combination of posts in the category Pedicure for a specific City is called by

```
<!-- Query for pedicuremanicure -->
<section>

    <div class="container">
        
        <?php 
        
        $PedicureManicure = 7 ;
        $PedicureManicureName = "Hand- en voetverzorging";
        
        $location_argument = array( 
        
        'category__and' => array( $location_id , $PedicureManicure) ,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        
        );
        
        $query = new WP_Query( $location_argument );
        
        ?>
                
        <div class="row">
        
        <?php 
        
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        
        ?>
        
        <h2><?php echo $PedicureManicureName; ?></h2>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
        
        <ul class="citydetails">
        
        <?php 
            
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            
            $query->the_post(); 
            
        ?>
        
        
        
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </a> - <?php the_field('afstand-van-anapurna') ?> km </li>
            
        
        
        
        <?php ;}} ?>
        
        </div>
        
        </ul>
        
        <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
        ?>
        

    </div>

</section>
<!-- End of query for pedicuremanicure -->
```

The combination of posts in the category Archeolohical for a specific City is called by

```
<!-- Query for Archeologische sites -->
<section>

    <div class="container">
        
        <?php 
        
        $ArcheologischeSites = 77 ;
        $ArcheologischeSitesName = "Archeologische sites";
        
        $location_argument = array( 
        
        'category__and' => array( $location_id , $ArcheologischeSites) ,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        
        );
        
        $query = new WP_Query( $location_argument );
        
        ?>
                
        <div class="row">
        
        <?php 
        
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        
        ?>
        
        <h2><?php echo $ArcheologischeSitesName; ?></h2>
        
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
        
        <ul class="citydetails">
        
        <?php 
            
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            
            $query->the_post(); 
            
        ?>
        
        
        
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </a> - <?php the_field('afstand-van-anapurna') ?> km </li>
            
        
        
        
        <?php ;}} ?>
        
        </div>
        
        </ul>
        
        <?php
            wp_reset_postdata();
            
        ?>
        

    </div>

</section>
<!-- End of query for Archeologische sites -->
```

I would however like to add all the subcategories of Beauty and Sightseeing in an array in order to avoid duplication of code for each new sub category I am adding to the structure. You can imagine that my current way of working is far from bullet proof and needs a lot of updating as soon as a new subcategory is added to the structure.